# Changing the App Language not working correctly (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Splash screen in my kotlin app, where I do some stuff like loading data. Currently it is only in german and I wanted to add english as additional language.
I've create the strings resources and so on.
Now I have added a bit of code to the Splash-Screen, where it checks, if the user already set a preferenced language (saved in sharedPreferences).

When there is nothing saved, a simple alertdialog pops up asking the user for his preference and sets everything accordingly.
Then the splashscreen is reloaded. When I choose english on my device (system language is german), the splash screen gets the correct string resources (english).

But when it changes to the MainActivity, it is german again. Only after restarting the app, everything is in english.

Here is how I change the language on my splashscreen:

```
    private lateinit var mainIntent : Intent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val prefs: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        var localeToSet: String? = prefs.getString("language", "")

        if(localeToSet == null || localeToSet.equals("")){
            val languages = arrayOf("Deutsch", "English")

            val langSelectorBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            langSelectorBuilder.setTitle(R.string.selectLanguageText)
            langSelectorBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            langSelectorBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(languages, -1) { dialog, selection ->
                when(selection) {
                    0 -> {
                        localeToSet = "de"
                        setLocale("de")
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        localeToSet = "en"
                        setLocale("en")
                    }
                }
                    recreate()
                    dialog.dismiss()
            }.setOnDismissListener {
                Handler().postDelayed({

                    startActivity(mainIntent)
                    finish()

                }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT)
            }
            langSelectorBuilder.create().show()
        }
        else{

                setLocale(localeToSet!!)

                Handler().postDelayed({

                    startActivity(mainIntent)
                    finish()

                }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT)

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)


    }

    private fun createIntent(localeToSet: String){

        mainIntent = Intent(this@SplashScreenActivity, MainActivity::class.java).apply {

            //Do stuff and pass data to mainactivity
    }

    private fun setLocale(localeToSet: String) {
        createIntent(localeToSet)

        val config = resources.configuration
        val locale = Locale(localeToSet)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        config.locale = locale
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
        val prefs: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()

        editor.putString("language", localeToSet)
        editor.apply()

    }
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance from living in an English-speaking country, but I'm curious. I've seen questions on here before where people are trying to put language settings in their app. Is this commonly found in apps on Google Play? Why not rely on the system setting for the language? If the system is set to German and your app has German resources, than it will automatically show your app in German. Won't it be annoying to users that they have to manually set the language in each individual app?

Comment: The problem is, when someone lives in germany, but has for example his phone set to hungarian, the way Android manages it as if it is not german, therefore that user would get english language (if English is set as default), even though that user would prefer to use german as language. Not everyone can speak or read english fluently :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize Android didn't let you set a queue of languages in order of preference. Seems like an obvious feature it should have.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the issue:

```
val langSelectorBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            langSelectorBuilder.setTitle(R.string.selectLanguageText)
            langSelectorBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            langSelectorBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(languages, -1) { dialog, selection ->
                when(selection) {
                    0 -> {
                        localeToSet = "de"
                        setLocale("de")
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        localeToSet = "en"
                        setLocale("en")
                    }
                }
                    recreate()
                    dialog.dismiss()
            }.setOnDismissListener {

                    finish()
            }
            langSelectorBuilder.create().show()
```

Without starting the MainActivity here, it works like it should